# looking for a program for mixing subliminals with music at automatic levels

Tags: software, mixing, home-studio

I am looking for a PC Audio mixing program that automatically mixes to sources at the same levels (floodgate). What I mean is that I want to mix subliminal messages in my music for me and I want to mix it to my favorite songs. So I need a program that no matter the levels on the songs and they go up or down it will keep the levels on the subliminal messages ate the right levels at all times. Thanks guys

Comment: I think some [DAW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) software will let you control a parameter based on a track's level. Maybe you could automate the level of your "subliminal" track based on the level of another track? I think Reaper can do this but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks Warrior Bob will check it out. Any idea is better than none. Will post how this works. Thanks You

Comment: Hey Warrior Bob I got a response from the Tech dept for reaper program and here is what was passed on to me. It sure can mix signals. If you want to maintain a fixed volume ratio between the music and the message track (controlled by the music track's level, that's not a trivial thing to set up. I attached a simple example project for you to experiment with. It uses parameter modulation to "ride" the level of the "Subliminal Buss" track, which contains a submix of the two other tracks "noise" and "messages" where you can insert WAVs with your messages and add noise.

Comment: I'm not sure where you'd attach it, but the concept seems sound!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly?  Max/MSP is a PERFECT program for this.

I don't know how you're making your subliminal messages (I assume you mean the binaural beat, brain wave trickery yes? - not saying it doesn't work, I've had bad success), but you can make your own brain wave sounds.

You could even create you're own music player to select songs (yours or otherwise) and have the amplitude of those songs tracked by Max/MSP; that data would then be control data to adjust the subliminal message you want.

Sound good?  I might be able to make an application for you but I think you'd get LOTS of fun out of Max/MSP.

Comment: I got an e-mail from musicbobbee - he's having trouble logging back in as himself and making comments. Here's to hoping he finds his way back.

His questions regarding Max/MSP:

You can do pretty much anything you want, but it's got a learning curve.  And you have to buy the program.  So, if you have access to the "white noise" and the 'subliminal' audio I can probably whip up an application that you can use that will let you select your 'song' and then do a real-time recording of them playing together.  But per your last comment it seems you are already able to do this with "reaper program?"

Comment: How many Bobs have we got in this question? :)

Comment: The irony of all us Bob's on such a topic seems like some sort of Darko time rift 0.o